How to use Restful API to make get request for taking chatbot performance from Langsmith
My project is developed using Vite.js for the frontend and Django for the backend. In this project, I have created a chatbot application and am using Langsmith for evaluation. However, I want to retrieve performance metrics from Langsmith and display them on my client interface. Are there any solutions to extract data from Langsmith using a RESTful API?
I have read documents about Langsmith already, but I can not find anything
